# How can I get my tests to work in React Native App?

Tags: facebook, react-native, npm

I am following the [FB's getting started docs for React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

And everything works great. It runs in Expo but when I try to test

```
    $ npm test
```

I get the following error and cannot figure out how to make the simple test run.

```
    > AwesomeProject@0.1.0 test /Users/Desktop/AwesomeProject
    > node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch

    2018-03-10 14:24 node[2805] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
    2018-03-10 14:24 node[2805] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
    2018-03-10 14:24 node[2805] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
    events.js:165
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^

    Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
         at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1386:9)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
         at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1389:12)
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing watchman (brew install watchman)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Any ideas why is this working?